# Array and curve modifier not working

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I am trying a stitch effect

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQkes.png)

and managed to make it on most of the project, but on some parts
is just impossible(as this one that I'm asking for help).. where is the mistake that makes it not follow the curve and look so distorted?

I'm ensuring the ''location of 0.0.0, rotation of 0.0.0 and scale of 1.1.1'' on both the curve and the stitch. Tried to rotate, scale, move it around. I even tried to change the orientation but with no success.

Does anyone knows how to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just zero out the delta transforms (x,y,z and rotation) of both objects and use x as deform axis.

Comment: Thank you, sir! it helped with the distortion part!

Still, I needed to change the position and rotation after doing what you told me to do. But I'm finally able to continue. Thank you very much.

Comment: you can parent both to an empty, then you can move & rotate the empty as you like